# sql query search removing end of string

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to search domain names ending in particular keywords. e.g. "car" would bring up buycar.com, but not carbuy.com.

So if my query is

```
SELECT * FROM domains WHERE LIKE '%car'
```

Will not show any results at all, obviously because the domains dont end in car, they end in .com, or .co, or something.

I think I need to do some sort of regex replace to search the domain, until the first `.`

Or whatever would do the equivalent of this in sql for php:

```
$pos = strpos($domain,'.');
$search = substr($domain,0,$pos);
```

So it would just search the actual domain without the TLD. Is this possible with sql?

Comment: You're missing the column name before `LIKE`.

Answer (score 4):

How about using:

```
SELECT *
FROM domains
WHERE domain LIKE '%car.%'
```

Comment: I only used "car" as an example, it could be anything

Comment: @Source . . . Then you would replace "car" with whatever you want to search.

Answer (score 0):

You could remove characters like `.com, .IR, .co` after `car` and run own query.

Please try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM domains
WHERE 
REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(domain),CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(domain))+1,LEN(domain 
))) LIKE '%car'
```

if you don't remove that character and use `Like '%car.%'` maybe get some thing like this: `car.site.com`